# Webp bg works on localhost but not on deployment tailwind + react

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, webp

I use a webp image for bg on my reactjs+tailwind webapp and when I run my app with npm start it works fine but when it's deployed on aws the background disappears. I use the same browser so I don't get what's wrong. The rest of my backgrounds that are created the same exact way but have png format or svg work just fine.

```
 backgroundImage: {
        backgroundShip3: "url('/src/website-assets/ship/ship_textured.webp')",
      }
```

Comment: The image is not where you think it is when deployed. What are you using to build and publish? Some tools will rename assets, others move them... This isn't related to webp or tailwind.

Comment: I use craco but when I run the same code with .png it works fine (I have both a png and webp version of the same file and I keep them in the same folder). I will try to upload it to aws and import it from a link though but I don't think it will help

Comment: ah. perhaps the .webp file isn't being recognized as used since it's in a stylesheet or something. Do a build and look at the files in your dist folder. I'm pretty sure you'll find the webp file is missing. I've used craco but using vite now, so can't answer better from memory.